# WPF Adding images to canvas without them being added as resources

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas

I am trying to add Images to my WPF application Canvas.
From what I understand, they need to be referenced as Resource in the VS Solution.
However, I need to be able to copy an image into a folder, and from an XML file the relative Uri of the image is parsed, and the image is loaded into the canvas :

```
    Image image = new Image();
    var pic = new BitmapImage();
    pic.BeginInit();
    pic.UriSource = new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative); // url is from the xml
    pic.EndInit();
    image.Source = pic;
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(image); //since the image is not in VS marked as Resource,
    // nothing shows up
```

Thank you for your kind advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the full path for the URI instead of using a `UriKind.Relative` uri, it will work properly:

```
pic.BeginInit();
pic.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Path\To\File.jpg");
pic.EndInit();
```

Comment: What about the part: "from an XML file the *relative* Uri of the image is parsed"?

Comment: @alterfox Just use `Path.Combine` to build the full URL - OP didn't show URL generation as it stands, so I couldn't include that...

Comment: Thanks for the solution